# React JS animations based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, redux

I am using React/Redux and am storing animation data in JSON and trying to get it to display on a React page.

I am using `setTimeout` (for pauses) and `setInterval` (for animation movement). However, I seem to be having trouble understanding how to implement the animations correctly and think I'm going about things totally the wrong way.

**JSON data:**

```
"objects": [

    {
        "title": "puppy",
        "image_set": [
            {
                "image": "images/puppy_sitting.png",
                "startx": 520,
                "starty": 28,
                "pause": 1000

            },
            {
                "image": "images/puppy_walking.png",
                "startx": 520,
                "starty": 28,
                "endx": 1,
                "endy": 1,
                "time": 1000
            },
            {
                "image": "images/puppy_crouching.png",
                "startx": 1,
                "starty": 1,
                "endx": 500,
                "endy": 400,
                "time": 2000
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "scorpion",
        "image_set": [
            {
                "image": "images/scorping_sleeping.png",
                "startx": 100,
                "starty": 400,
                "pause": 5000

            },
            {
                "image": "images/scorpion_walking.png",
                "startx": 100,
                "starty": 400,
                "endx": 500,
                "endy": 400,
                "time": 7000
            },
            {
                "image": "images/scorpion_walking.png",
                "startx": 500,
                "starty": 400,
                "endx": 100,
                "endy": 400,
                "time": 2000
            },
            {
                "image": "images/scorpion_walking.png",
                "startx": 100,
                "starty": 400,
                "endx": 200,
                "endy": 400,
                "time": 7000
            },
            {
                "image": "images/scorpion_walking.png",
                "startx": 200,
                "starty": 400,
                "endx": 100,
                "endy": 400,
                "time": 1000
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Each object can have several images related to them. The animations will continue to repeat non-stop. Each object should move concurrently with each of the other objects so that I can create a scene of various animals and objects moving around it.

**Animation code:**

I'm pretty sure I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but my code looks something like this:

```
  // image_set is the list of images for a specific object
  // object_num is the array index corresponding to the JSON objects array
  // selected is the array index corresponding to which image in the image_set will be displayed
  runAnimation(image_set, object_num, selected){

        // Uses prevState so that we keep state immutable
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let images = [...prevState.images];

            if (!images[object_num]){
                images.push({image: null, x: 0, y: 0})

            }

            images[object_num].image = image_set[selected].image;
            images[object_num].x = this.getFactoredX(image_set[selected].startx);
            images[object_num].y = this.getFactoredY(image_set[selected].starty);
            return {images: images};
        })

        if (image_set[selected].endx && image_set[selected].endy && image_set[selected].time){
                let x = this.getFactoredX(image_set[selected].startx)
                let y = this.getFactoredY(image_set[selected].starty)
                let startx = x
                let starty = y
                let endx = this.getFactoredX(image_set[selected].endx)
                let endy = this.getFactoredY(image_set[selected].endy)
                let time = image_set[selected].time

                let x_increment = (endx - x) / (time / 50)
                let y_increment = (endy - y) / (time / 50)



                let int = setInterval(function(){

                        x += x_increment
                        y += y_increment


                        if (x > endx || y > endy){
                                clearInterval(int)
                        }

                        this.setState(prevState => {
                                let images = [...prevState.images]

                                if (images[object_num]){
                                        images[object_num].x = x
                                        images[object_num].y = y
                                }


                                return {images: images};


                        })


                }.bind(this),
                 50
                )

        }

        if (image_set[selected].pause && image_set[selected].pause > 0){
                selected++

                if (selected == image_set.length){
                        selected = 0
                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                        this.runAnimation(image_set, object_num, selected)

                }.bind(this),
                  image_set[selected].pause
                )

        }
        else {
                selected++

                if (selected == image_set.length){
                        selected = 0
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                        this.runAnimation(image_set, object_num, selected)

                }.bind(this),
                        50
                )
        }


  }
```

**Redux and this.props.data**

Redux brings in the data as props. So, I have a function called from my componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps functions that passes the original image set into the loadAnimationFunction.

**My render()**

In my `render()` function I have something like this:

```
if (this.state.images.length > 1){
    animated = this.state.images.map((image, i) => {
            let x_coord = image.x
            let y_coord = image.y
            return (
                     <div key={i} style={{transform: "scale(" + this.state.x_factor + ")", transformOrigin: "top left", position: "absolute", left: x_coord, top: y_coord}}>
                            <img src={`/api/get_image.php?image=${image.image}`} />
                    </div>
            )

    })
}
```

**x_factor / y_factor**

Throughout my code there is also reference to x and y factor. This is because the background that the animations appear in may be scaled smaller or larger. Therefore I also scale the position of the starting and ending x/y coordinates for each animation as well as scale the animated images themselves.

**time and pause time**

Time indicates the time in ms that the animation should take. Pause time indicates how long in ms to pause before moving to the next animation.

**The problem**

The code does not move the animations smoothly and they seem to jump around sporadically.

Also, when I click the mouse anywhere on the page it causes the animations to jump to another position. Why would clicking the mouse affect the animation?

One thing I've noticed is that if I have the console open for debugging purposes, this really slows down the animations.

What can I do to my code so that the animations work as expected?

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to animate your element using a `setInterval` doing a `setState` of the coordinates and with an `absolute` position. All of these cannot achieve great performance.

First, `setInterval` should never be used for animations, and you should prefer [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as it will allow 60fps animations since the animation will be run before the next repaint of the browser.

Second, doing a `setState` would re-render your whole component which could potentially have an impact on the rendering timing as I assume your component doesn't render only your images. You should try to avoid at maximum to re-render things that haven't changed, so try to isolate your images for the animations.

Lastly, when you *position* your element with `left` and `top` properties, but you should stick to that, positioning, and not animating as the browser would do the animation pixel by pixel and would not be able to create good performances. Instead, you should use CSS [`translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate), as it can do sub-pixel calculation and will work on the GPU instead, allowing you to achieve 60fps animations. There is a [good article](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) on that by Paul Irish.

---

That being said, you should probably use [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) which would allow you a smooth animation:

```
import { Motion, spring } from 'react-motion'

<Motion defaultStyle={{ x: 0 }} style={{ x: spring(image.x), y: spring(image.y) }}>
  {({ x, y }) => (
    <div style={{
       transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
    }}>
      <img src={`/api/get_image.php?image=${image.image}`} />
    </div>
  )}
</Motion>
```

There is also the React Transition Group, [Transition](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition) could move your elements using a `translate` animation like explained above. You should also go take a look at the react animations docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html).

Worth a try too, is [React Pose](https://popmotion.io/pose), which is pretty easy to use and also performs quite well with a clean API. [Here](https://popmotion.io/pose/learn/popmotion-get-started/) is the get started page for React.

---

Here is a quick demo using your concept with a sit/walking/running cycle. Notice how react-motion is the only one to handle the transition in between the frames without hardcoding the duration of the transition, which would [go against a fluid UI](https://twitter.com/andy_matuschak/status/566736015188963328), the state only handles going through the different steps.

Quoting the react-motion [Readme](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion#what-does-this-library-try-to-solve):

> For 95% of use-cases of animating components, we don't have to resort to using hard-coded easing curves and duration. Set up a stiffness and damping for your UI element, and let the magic of physics take care of the rest. This way, you don't have to worry about petty situations such as interrupted animation behavior. It also greatly simplifies the API.

If you are not satisfied with the default spring, you can change the `dampling` and `stiffness` parameters. There's an [app](http://chenglou.me/react-motion/demos/demo5-spring-parameters-chooser/) which could help you get the one which satisfy you the most.

[image: demo]

<kbd>**[Source](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qpwkvwm8j)**</kbd>

Comment: looks cool, but does not respect the animation time (for instance your third animation is 2 seconds, during which the position should be interpolated between the start and end)

Comment: I have... The Idea is to animate from start x to end x and that animation should take 2s. I am not saying you need to compute the steps or something like that

Comment: With that said I understand your point about the fluid ui... But then you should calculate a speed and use it because your animation is just wrong

Answer (score 2):

React is not exactly meant to be used for animations. I'm not saying you *can't* animate react components, but it's not part of the problem domain react tries to solve. What it does do is provide you with a nice framework to have the several UI pieces interact with each other. I.e. when creating a game for instance, you'll use react and redux to create and manage the screens, buttons etc. however the game itself, would be separately contained and not use react.

Just a long-winded way to say that if you want to use animations react will not suffice, it's better to use something like greensock's animation library: https://greensock.com/
They provide a tutorial on how to use it in conjunction with react: https://greensock.com/react

Answer (score 1):

**Let css do the transitions. Use transform: translate instead of top and left.**

The animations you have in your sample are very easy to express with css `transition`, `transition-delay`, and `transform`.
I would put my effort in converting the JSON to css (using a cssInJs solution that allows you to generate the classes on the fly) and apply those classes to the images.

**something like this(working example with your JSON sample):**  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-animate-json

```
const App = () =>
  <div>
    {objects.map(object =>
      <Item item={object} />)
    }
  </div>
```

Item.js:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: 0, classNames: {} }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.nextImage();
    this.generateClassNames();
  }

  generateClassNames = () => {
    const stylesArray = this.props.item.image_set.flatMap((image, index) => {
      const { startx, starty, endx = startx, endy = starty, time } = image;
      return [{
        [`image${index}_start`]: {
          transform: `translate(${startx}px,${starty}px)`,
          transition: `all ${time || 0}ms linear`
        }
      }, {
        [`image${index}_end`]: { transform: `translate(${endx}px,${endy}px)` }
      }]
    });

    const styles = stylesArray.reduce((res, style) => ({ ...res, ...style }), {})

    const { classes: classNames } = jss.createStyleSheet(styles).attach();
    this.setState({ classNames });
  }

  nextImage = async () => {
    const { image_set } = this.props.item;
    let currentImage = image_set[this.state.selected];
    await wait(currentImage.pause);
    await wait(currentImage.time);

    this.setState(({ selected }) =>
      ({ selected: (selected + 1) % image_set.length }), this.nextImage)
  }

  render() {
    const { selected, classNames } = this.state;
    const startClassName = classNames[`image${selected}_start`];
    const endClassName = classNames[`image${selected}_end`];
    return <img
      className={`${startClassName} ${endClassName}`}
      src={this.props.item.image_set[selected].image}
    />
  }
}

const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your fundamental problem lies in the way React/Redux handle state. React may batch multiple update requests together to make rendering more efficient. Without further diagnostic measures, my guess is that the state handling after `setState` will just respond too rigidly.

The solution would to update your animation *outside* the state system, either using a ready-made framework or simply by taking care of the animation yourself; get a reference to the element and update it instead of re-rendering the element every time the state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

without going deep about animations in JS (there are already plently of valid answers here) you should consider how you render your images:

```
<div key={i} style={{transform: "scale(" + this.state.x_factor + ")", transformOrigin: "top left", position: "absolute", left: x_coord, top: y_coord}}>
    <img src={`/api/get_image.php?image=${image.image}`} />
</div>
```

You should actually see a warning when compiling this (or was it in the docs?) because you use the loop index as the key. This should lead to an image object being rendered in different divs as more images are added/removed. This is especially critically if you have a css-transition effect on the div.
TLDR: use some identifier as the `key` instead of the variable `i` (may be generate one when you create the animation?)
Also if you have a css transition on the div, you should remove it, because together with the changes from setInterval the transition calculation won't be able to keep up with the changes.